# How to get hrefs of dynamically changed links using selenium python?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium

How do I get all hrefs(links) that reside in anchor tags with JavaScript code using selenium python? Those links are dynamically changed every time.
this is the tag i have used to click:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSMaf.png)

i got all the anchor tags inside that webpage, but for above anchor tag i got output like this

javascript:selectItem('/7000/7020.aspx?reqID=' + ContentPH_hidReqID.getValue() + '&wf=0' + addUrlText() + '#ContentPH_tabReq:ContentPH_pnlCandidates')

Anyone can help me out how to get those type of links on webpage using selenium python.

Thanks in advance 
himabindu y

Comment: share the html code

Comment: Stack overflow is not a free code design and writing service. Please show us what you have attempted and explain why it is wrong.

Comment: @cruisepandey here is the html code you ask for

Comment: @cruisepandey    <a href="javascript:selectItem('/7000/7020.aspx?reqID=' + 571461 + '&amp;wf=0' + addUrlText())">571461</a>

Comment: @cruisepandey  I could not paste the whole html because its huge one. From the above html i pasted 571461 is obtained through javascript. i am trying to get all href from webpage . i got all the hrefs but for above link i got like this javascript:selectItem('/7000/7020.aspx?reqID=' + ContentPH_hidReqID.getValue() + '&wf=0' + addUrlText() + '#ContentPH_tabReq:ContentPH_pnlCandidates') . can you help me how to extract that ReqID from that tag. and how to get that type of links in that webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this to find all anchor link elements on the page that have href

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href]");
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. i have tried this one. it gives only hrefs outside the webpage. i need inside div anchor tags hrefs also. inside they are using javascript code .

Comment: <a href="javascript:selectItem('/7000/7020.aspx?reqID=' + 571461 + '&amp;wf=0' + addUrlText())">571461</a> if it is in this format

Comment: I think OP's question is based on _JavaScript_ bindings. The answer is through _Python_. @himabinduyeddala if that suffice to your requirement update the question accordingly.